# No more asynchronous or callback from rxjs 6.X in Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, service, callback, rxjs

```
I have a simple service in Angular-6 app.

console.log("01: try to get Users...");
    let subScription = this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.Users = data;
        console.log("03: set users...");
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error("Error to get data: ", error)
      },
      () => {
        console.log("04: complete get data....", )
      });

    console.log("02: return control to function call if service works like a promise")
```

If I use an older version of rxjs, the output of console.log is:

```
01: try to get Users...
02: return control to function call if service works like a promise
03: set users...
04: complete get data
```

Using RxJS 6.X the output is like the following:

```
01: try to get Users...
03: set users...
04: complete get data
02: return control to function call if service works like a promise
```

Does anyone have the same problem? If yes, then how to fix this to work just like before?

thanks,

Austin

Comment: "if service works like a promise" the output you've given for RxJS 6 cannot occur. RxJS cannot magic away asynchrony.

Comment: The implementation of `getUsers` must have changed. Mind sharing the code?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to show the code for `userService.getUsers()` before we could say why it is behaving the way it is.

However, if you want to *force* it to be async, then you can schedule the subscription on the asap scheduler like so:

```
import {subscribeOn} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {asapScheduler} from 'rxjs';

// ...
this.userService.getUsers().pipe(subscribeOn(asapScheduler)).subscribe(...)
```

This ensures that the subscribe call happens asynchronously and will give you the behaviour you had before.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In this case, I return mock data, I need to add delay(10) some amount of time to make it works just like before.
    return usersObservable.pipe(delay(10),.....)